# Extracting nested value from an RDD Tuple

Tags: apache-spark

EDITED.

I appear a little rusty it appears.

The following snippet:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

val inputPath: String = "/FileStore/tables/g1.txt" //does work
val rdd = spark.read.text(inputPath)
   .select(input_file_name, $"value")   
   .as[(String, String)]  
   .rdd
val rdd2 = rdd.map(line => (line._1, line._2.split(",")))
```

returns:

```
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Array[String])] = MapPartitionsRDD[52] at map at command-2326393392121655:9
res13: Array[(String, Array[String])] = Array((dbfs:/FileStore/tables/g1.txt,Array(0, 5, 10)), (dbfs:/FileStore/tables/g1.txt,Array(202008, 5, 10)), (dbfs:/FileStore/tables/g1.txt,Array(202009, 10, 20)))
```

I want to get the 2nd element of the Array remaining in RDD domain. Somehow, cannot do it.

Selecting as per below having converted to a DF, I can get the Int value out no worries. But I am interested in the RDD approach. E.g.:

```
df.select($"value".getField("_2")).show(false)
```

returns correctly:

```
5,5,10
```

However, I cannot achieve the same with an RDD. Things like:

```
val rddx = rddx-1.map(x => (x._2._2))
```

DF works easier, curious as to what the easiest way with an RDD would be.

Comment: You can use the Dataframe approach and then call df.rdd to get the rdd

Comment: Also since it's an array you should do: `val rddx = rddx-1.map(x => x._2(1))` if the array always has more than 1 element or add an `if .. else`

Comment: If that is the answer post it pls.

Comment: I've posted it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your ask to extract only the second element of the array fixing your code below:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.input_file_name

val inputPath: String = "/FileStore/tables/g1.txt" //does work
val rdd = spark.read.text(inputPath)
    .select(input_file_name, $"value")   
    .as[(String, String)]  
    .rdd
val rdd2 = rdd.map(line => (line._1, line._2.split(",").lift(1).getOrElse("0").toInt))
```